# How do you create and use a Collection that has as one of its members a Collection

Tags: c#

I’m trying to create a Collection that will have a Collection as one of its members.    The application is to track stock prices.

The primary collection should look like this:      **Symbol, Stock Name, (price collection’)**

The ‘price collection’ should look like this:      **Date, Price**

Some example data

APPL, Apple
[1/1/2011,$245;1/2/2011,$247;1/3/2011,$242; .....]

MS, Microsoft
[1/1/2011,$35;1/2/2011,$32;1/3/2011,$42; .....]

So in c# how do I create a collection class that has a collection class as a member?  Then how do I access the ‘price collection’ members of that collection?  (I’ve managed to figure out the creation and able to add at both levels, but I can only access the top level to see contents.  I can’t figure out how to access ‘prices’ that I’ve added nor can I see any of its methods

Answer (score 1):

[**`List<T>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a generic class that can hold a collection of class instances of any type. So just create a class that holds another collection as one of its members (sample only):

```
class Stock
{
  public Symbol {get;set;}
  public Name {get;set;}
  public List<Quote> Quotes {get;set;}
}
```

Now create a `List<Stock>` and populate the `Prices` member for each Stock you add to the collection, i.e.

```
var myStocks = new List<Stock>();
Stock stock = new Stock() 
{ 
  Symbol = "MSFT",
  ..
  Quotes = new List<Quote>()
}
myStocks.Add(stock);
```

You can access the prices by accessing it just like any other member:

```
foreach(Stock stock in myStocks)
{
  foreach(Quote quote in stock.Quotes)
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}$", quote.Date, quote.Price));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with List inside List.  For your example, it can be

```
public class PriceList
{
  DateTime priceTime;
  Double price;
}
public class QuoteList
{
  String symbol;
  String stockName;
  PriceList priceCollection;
}

List<QuoteList> myQuote = new List<QuoteList>();
```

QuoteList will be treated as the normal List collection like integer list or string list with Add, Remove, Fetch operations.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll probably have a `Stock` and a `Price` class, for example:

```
public class Price 
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The `Price` class has a date and a price property (I don't like the name of this class, but just for illustration). The `Price` class will be used in the collection of prices for each `Stock`:

```
public class Stock 
{
    private readonly IList<Price> _prices = new List<Price>();

    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Price> Prices 
    {
        get { return _prices; }
    }
}
```

I chose a generic `IList` to keep it simple. There are other collection objects to choose from but this should suit your needs sufficiently. To get a list of `Stock` objects that each have an empty list of `Price` objects, you can simply build up new `IList<Stock>`:

```
IList<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
```

And then create and add `Stock` objects to it with new additions to the `Prices` collection:

```
var appleStock = new Stock { Name = "Apple", Symbol = "APPL" };
appleStock.Prices.Add(new Price { Date = new DateTime(8, 23, 2011), Price = 199.43 });
appleStock.Prices.Add(new Price { Date = new DateTime(8, 25, 2011), Price = 206.28 });

stocks.Add(appleStock);

var googleStock = new Stock { Name = "Google", Symbol = "GOOG" };
googleStock.Prices.Add(/* same as above */);

stocks.Add(googleStock);
```

And on and on until you have your list of `Stock`s built up. I've made some basic assumptions about where you're data is coming from so your actual code may be very different, but I hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Price
{
  DateTime priceTime;
  Double price;
}
class Quote
{
  String symbol;
  String stockName;
  Price[] priceCollection;
}

List<Quote> myQuote = new List<Quote>();
```